# WordPress MU: Login from main page but not individual blogs

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

I recently upgraded to **WPMU 2.8.6** and ever since, my users can't log in on their individual blogs, but they can log in from the main page.

My site is at `blogs.mtwp.net` (we're a school district).

So if a user goes to `blogs.mtwp.net/BLOGNAME/wp-login.php`, their password is rejected. If they go to `blogs.mtwp.net/wp-login.php`, they can log in and get to the dashboard from there.

But it's not *all* users. Site admins can get in just fine.

We're using **wpDirAuth 1.4** if that makes a difference.

Honestly, I'm stumped. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would seem to have enabled the WPdirauth plugin at the top level blog but not on others. Only your top level blog will have the necessary information to connect to your directory.

Site admins are not typically part of your internal directory - they're a Wordpress user which means they can still log-in ok without needing to connect to Active Directory or whatever you're using.

Enable WPdirauth on all blogs that you need users to login to.

Comment: Jim, thanks a million! Used to work, but I guess something in the upgrade changed it. You've made a lot of people very happy! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try reviewing your wp-config file.  You should see something like this:

```
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
```

Depending on how you've configured Wordpress, this must be enabled to log in to the dashboard of secondary sites.